# Returning the last element of a container that has no back() method in C++?

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11, iterator, containers

What is the best method to return the last element in a container that does not provide a `back()` member function, such as `std::set`?

Since the `end()` method returns an iterator to the first element after the end of the container, is the only way of grabbing the last element to decrement the iterator before dereferencing it?

Such as:

```cpp
std::set<int> set = {1,2,3,4,5};

int end = *(set.end());
int beforeEnd = *(--set.end());

std::cout << "set.end() -> " << end << std::endl;
std::cout << "--set.end() -> " << beforeEnd << std::endl;
```

However, these both return:

```
set.end() -> 5
--set.end() -> 5
```

Is this the proper way of getting the last element, and why do these return the same value?

Comment: `int end = *(set.end());` is _undefined behavior_.

Comment: You can't dereference the `end` iterator, in *any* container

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is the only way of grabbing the last element to decrement the iterator
>   before dereferencing it?

No, there are also other options.

The simplest way is using the reverse iterators(both `std::set::rbegin` or `std::set::crbegin`), which dirctly give you the element which is one past `std::set`s *end* iterator.

From [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/rbegin), `std::set::rbegin and std::set::crbegin`

> Returns a reverse iterator to the **first element of the reversed**
>   **container**. It corresponds to the **last element of the non-reversed**
>   **container**. If the container is empty, the returned iterator is equal
>   to rend().

```
std::set<int> set = { 1,2,3,4,5 };

auto iter = set.rbegin();
const int beforeEndIter = *iter;
std::cout << "--set.end() -> " << beforeEndIter  << '\n';
```

(*update*) in case of the second last element in the container(i.e. two past the *end* iterator),  use [std::next](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/next) for the same reason mentioned in the other answer for `std::prev`. **[See a demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/fWzab3i409nz2KgL)**

```
std::set<int> set = {1, 2};

const bool hasElements = set.cbegin() != set.cend();
auto iter = set.rbegin();
if(hasElements && iter != set.rend())            std::cout << "--set.end() -> " << *iter << '\n';
if(hasElements && std::next(iter) != set.rend()) std::cout << "two past set.end() -> " << *std::next(iter) << '\n';
```

**outputs**:

```
--set.end() -> 2
two past set.end() -> 1
```

The second option has been mentioned in the other answer.

---

On the other hand, dereferencing the end iterator is an [undefined behavior](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub), in which you could expect any result. In your case, you have got the last element(i.e. one past end iterator) of the container.

Comment: Question is tagged with C++11 so `auto` would do fine too

Comment: Thanks, a reverse iterator makes more sense. Much appreciated

Comment: There's nothing wrong with "decrement[ing] the [end] iterator **before** dereferencing it". `*--set.end()`, if it compiles, is a reference to the last element. As pointed out in one answer, this would be better written as `*std::prev(set.end())`. Or it could be `auto iter = set.end(); std::cout << *--iter << '\n';`

Answer (score 3):

This

```
int end = *(set.end());
```

As commented by [πάντα ῥεῖ](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1413395/%cf%80%ce%ac%ce%bd%cf%84%ce%b1-%e1%bf%a5%ce%b5%e1%bf%96), has undefined behavior. That's because `std::set::end`

> Returns an iterator to the element **following the last element** of the container. This element acts as a placeholder; attempting to access it results in undefined behavior.
>   (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/end, emphasis mine)

The other line:

```
int beforeEnd = *(--set.end());
```

It's not guarateed to work. See e.g. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/prev, emphasis mine:

> Although the expression `--c.end()` often compiles, it is not guaranteed to do so: `c.end()` is an *rvalue* expression, and **there is no iterator requirement that specifies that decrement of an rvalue is guaranteed to work**. In particular, when iterators are implemented as pointers, `--c.end()` does not compile, while `std::prev(c.end())` does.

So it may fail for the same reason that this wouldn't compile:

```
int arr[4] = {1,2,3,4};
int *p = --(arr + 4); // --> error: expression is not assignable
```

You can write something like the following, instead.

```
std::set<int> set = {1,2,3,4,5};

if ( set.begin() != set.end() )
{
    auto itLast = std::prev(set.end());

    std::cout << "last -> " << *itLast << '\n';
}
```

Comment: Why would `--c.end()` fail to compile if `end()` returns a pointer? Decrementing a pointer is well-defined behavior. Why would the pointer being an rvalue change that?

Comment: @RemyLebeau Decrementing the pointer [yes](https://wandbox.org/permlink/wp5hJS0SG8eT93yO), it's well defined, but they are referring to the [expression](https://wandbox.org/permlink/4vLx4iyCmAYiqbMG).